# A question about tensor product of algebras of compact operators.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Let $\cal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\cal{K(\cal{H})}$ the algebra of compact operators acting on $\cal{H}$. Then
$$\cal{K(\cal{H})}\otimes\cal{K}(\cal{H})\cong\cal{K}(\cal{H}\otimes H).$$

How to prove it? I can find a mapping $\phi$ from  $\cal{K(\cal{H})}\otimes\cal{K}(\cal{H})$ to $\cal{B}(H\otimes\cal{H})$, but there is some difficult to prove the range of $\phi$ is justly $\cal{K}(\cal{H}\otimes H)$.

P.S.: Is $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})\otimes\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})\cong\mathbb{M}_{n^2}(\mathbb{C})$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212209/mathcalkl2-mathbbrm-times-mathbbrn-mathcalkl2-mathbbr/537330) is the same question. Unfortnately I can't close this one because no one had upvoted answer for the latter question.

Comment: You are wellcome!